# Is their an equivalent of react natives "Hot Reloading" for native iOS Simulator development?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, ios-simulator, hot-reload

I'm wondering if there is a way to see UI changes in an iOS application without having to restart the device or simulator. I know in react native since they use Javascript you're able to make a change to the background colour of a view and the background would reflect that change without having to restart the simulator. So I'm thinking since react native just converts javascript into native app code this might be possible in Native Development? Yes no maybe?

Comment: Have you checked out [Sherlock](https://sherlock.inspiredcode.io/)? It's not _exactly_ what you want (SwiftUI, the way to write declarative UI for Apple platforms is the way to go), but it lets you edit views and layout constraints in real-time without building your application -- you have to do it through the Sherlock macOS application, but it's better than nothing. It costs, though.

Comment: Thanks but rightr now i need all free software. Its not a big deal, its just when I'm doing little incremental changes to a UI and then waiting for the simulator to pop up takes time....annoying time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing normal native iOS development in the typical way -- no.

But, if you reproduce what ReactNative is doing (defining a data format for UI, loading it, and then wiring it up dynamically), then you can re-create it.

You might want to look into SwiftUI, which gives you a way to preview in Xcode without running the entire app.

Without that, if you use modules for all your UI code, you could incorporate a playground and see live changes as you code as well.

Comment: Whats swift UI? Is that a cocoa pod?

Comment: SwiftUI is Apple's new way to build UI. It's only supported in the latest OS's, but works on phones, iPads, Macs, TV, and watch.  It's more like React (immutable tree of views that gets diffed) with an Rx style way of passing data (called Combine). There are a bunch of videos from WWDC 2019 that explain it.

Comment: It's a completely different way of building UI.  It's the future, but perhaps not appropriate for most apps today. No iOS12 support -- very new (with lots of bugs / limitations)

Comment: I am personally using it for a watch app, because it's way better than what you had to do before.

Comment: Issue is im not creating a new app I'm updating an older one. So were going to keep it as is until the time is right

Comment: If your app is very big, break out modules and make mini apps just for fast development. We recently did that and it works well